# How to make different item list with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Its working but..  **href=** doesnt work , i dont know why. ANd when mouse hover of items.. I can not click button and i can not click the avatar ?.. Thank for answer.

[You can check example from here.](http://jsbin.com/ayodas/1/edit)

Comment: _Its working but.. doesnt work_ ?

Comment: What isn't working? We aren't mind readers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description wasn't very helpful as the comments above mentioned. But I've created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RA6vQ/) from your above code, and this seems to run fine. The only things I have changed are as follows.

On your `on` trigger you have targeted `".kisiliste<?=$sayfa?> .kisi"`... I can only assume `.kisiliste<?=$sayfa?>` references a html element you have not included. So i changed this to simply `.kisi`.

Also I added a `;` to the end of your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations. Apart from that it works fine.

Please don't to forget to tick answers if they help.

**EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------**

The issue is to do with your css. [Please see this fixed link.](http://jsbin.com/ayodas/4/edit)

I have changed two elements.

From `#kisiliste .kisi .sabitle{}` I removed `z-index:-1`

and have added a block display on `#kisiliste .kisi .sabitle .avatar a{display:block}`

This seems to have sorted the issues for both the hover problem and the avatar click.

Comment: I added example, you can check now.